# Get value from dbSet in foreach

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the below statement. But i am unable to get data from the query into my foreach. What am i doing wrong?
I know the statement itself works, but am unable to get the values from it, within my foreach.

```
var products = db.Products.Select(x => x.Id).Where(x => x.Contains(zipcode.ToString()));
if (suppliers.Any())
{
    foreach (var p in products)
    {
    // found one
    // p.Id does not work?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you select here `.Select(x => x.Id)` already the `Id` and you dont iterate over products. you iterate over `typeof(Id)` which seems to be `string`

instead you should try

```
db.Products.Where(x => x.Id.Contains(zipcode.ToString()));
```